# Full browser Jquery Carousel with different heights leaves gaps below footer

Tags: jquery, footer, carousel

I am using the Flexisel jQuery carousel as a portfolio site. I have gotten it to work like this so far:
http://www.frankotoole.com/flexisel/9bit/flexisel.html

I like how this site works (having a series of long pages of various lengths connected by arrows): http://www.ikeafamilylivemagazine.com/us/en/article/32269

How can I make the shorter pages on my portfolio site (after you click right or left from my landing slide) not have the white space below the footer? It seems like the browser is basing the height of the page on the longest slide in the carousel, but I don't want viewers to be able to scroll below the footer when there is a shorter slide.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.